# MS ACCESS – Return a daily count of booked resources within a date range

Tags: sql, ms-access

Please note: *this is not for an Access project as such, but a legacy application that uses an Access database for its back end.*

**Setup**
Part of the application is a kind of Gantt chart, fixed to single day columns, where each row represents a single resource. Resources are booked out for a range of days and a booking is for a single resource, so they cannot overlap on a row. The range of dates that is in view is user selectable, open ended, and can be changed by various methods, including horizontal scrolling using mouse or keyboard.

**Problem**
I've been tasked with adding a row to the top of the chart to indicate overall resource usage for each day. Of course that's trivially easy to do by simply querying for each day in the range separately, but unfortunately that is proving to be an expensive process and therefore slows down horizontal scrolling a lot. So I'm looking for a way to do it more efficiently, hopefully with fewer database reads.

Here is a highly simplified example of the bookings table:

```
booking_ID |   start_Date |    end_Date |  resource_ID
----------- -------------- ------------- -------------
         1     2014-07-17    2014-07-20             21
         2     2014-08-24    2014-08-29              4
         3     2014-08-26    2014-09-02             21
         4     2014-08-28    2014-09-04             19
```

Ideally, I would like a single query that returns each day within the specified range, along with a count of how many bookings there are on those days. So querying the data above for 20 days from 2014-07-17 would produce this:

```
check_Date | resources_Used 
----------- ---------------
2014-07-17                1
2014-07-18                1
2014-07-19                1
2014-07-20                1
2014-07-21                0
2014-07-22                0
2014-07-23                0
2014-08-24                1
2014-08-25                1
2014-08-26                2
2014-08-27                2
2014-08-28                3
2014-08-29                3
2014-08-30                2
2014-08-31                2
2014-09-01                2
2014-09-02                2
2014-09-03                1
2014-09-04                1
2014-09-05                0
```

I can get a list of dates in the range by using a table of integers (starting at 0), with this:

```
SELECT CDATE('2014-07-17') + ID AS check_Date FROM Integers WHERE ID < 20
```

And I can get the count of resources used for a single day with something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS resources_Used 
FROM booking 
WHERE start_Date <= CDATE('2014-09-04')
AND end_Date >= CDATE('2014-09-04')
```

But I can't figure out how (or if) I can tie them both together to get the desired results. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table called "calendar" and put a list of dates into it covering the necessary timeframe. It just needs one column called check_date with one row for each date. Use Excel, start at whatever date and just drag down, then import into the new table.

After your calendar table is set up you can run the following:

```
select c.check_date, count(b.resource_id) as resources_used
  from calendar c, bookings b
 where c.check_date between b.start_date and b.end_date
group by c.check_date
```

Comment: Thanks. That's given me the linking method I needed, but I didn't really want to be writing out to a calendar table, so I just substituted `calendar` in the from clause with the `Integers` query I mentioned in parentheses and it seems to work okay. Can you see any problems in doing it that way?

Comment: It might run a little faster with the calendar table but if the results are the same and it doesn't take much longer then it should be fine. If it were a better database like oracle you could use the connect by clause to derive rows from the start_date and end_date of single rows but I don't believe there is anything of that sort in Access (at least not strictly sql)

Comment: Yes I've just discovered that it's not as fast as I'd like now that I've plugged it into the application. It's a lot better than it was before but not quite where I'd like it to be, so I'll try the calendar method next. It'll have to be tomorrow though as it's already way past my bedtime :)

Comment: @Ants1060 - You _want_ a calendar table, they're stupidly useful; put indices over stuff that's normally a computed value (like `week` or `day-of-week`), and they could be used by the optimizer (although I don't know how smart Access' is).  For companies with a retail calendar (4-5-4 or similar), it's the best in-db way to translate fiscal dates.  Holidays are now a simple Boolean flag.

Comment: Sadly, using a calendar table doesn't improve the horizontal scrolling speed at all – or at least not enough to make it usable. The more columns (dates) I have to cater for – there can be as few as 10 or as many as 150, depending on zoom level, application size, and screen resolution – the slower it is. To get the kind of speed I'm looking for I think I'm going to have to create and maintain a 'Usage' table to keep track of daily booking rates – which will be a pain, but I can't see any other way around it. I'm open to suggestions...

Comment: I am accepting this solution now, though, as it *is* the answer to the question I asked.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - Thanks. I can see their utility now. And although it appears it's not going to be the answer to *this* particular problem, I will certainly bear it in mind as a useful device.